# Reference in dolphin flipping a coin in front of a yellow sports car scene

Tags: reference, the-simpsons

Which movie reference is this, in *The Simpsons* - Night Of The Dolphins (S12E01-Treehouse of Horror 11), A dolphin is flipping a coin in front of a yellow sports car.

[image]

Is this a 1932 Ford Standard Coupe (Milner Coupe), so reference would be to American Graffiti? But in this movie, no such exact scene occurs.

Comment: Are u asking about the entire sketch or just this car flipping scene?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100274/what-does-the-coin-flipping-before-dying-mean

Comment: Just the coin flipping scene with the car behind the dolphin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's probably a reference to the coin-flipping gangster trope from the 1930s.

The old car and the tough demeanor of the dolphin flipping a coin is most likely a reference to the coin-flipping gangster/tough-guy trope that was [originated by George Raft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Raft) in the 1932 film [*Scarface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarface_(1932_film)). This trope was widely used during the 1930s and 1940s, so it is difficult to say if there is a specific film that is being parodied, or just the trope.

### The fact that the 1932 Ford is yellow could be a reference to *American Grafitti*

In the era of black and white movies when the coin-flipping trope was at its height, you would not have been able to tell if a car was yellow, and the vast majority of them were dark-toned. However, [a yellow 1932 Ford did appear](https://www.macsmotorcitygarage.com/the-real-star-of-american-graffiti-milners-32-ford-coupe/) in the 1973 film *American Grafitti*, so it is possibly a reference. That said, there is nothing else about the scene or the episode that in any other way recalls *American Grafitti*, so if it is a reference, it is an oblique one that stands alone.